# Dependency Injection - The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context - MethodAccessException was unhandled

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, compiler-errors, ninject

Code Sample:

```
namespace DependencyInjection
{
class Program  
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        var samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
   }       
}



class Samurai
{
    readonly IWeapon _weapon;
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        _weapon = weapon;
    }
    public void Attack(string target)
    {
        _weapon.Hit(target);
    }
}

interface IWeapon
{
    void Hit(string target);
}

class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sword - ", target);
    }
}

class Arrow : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrow - ", target);
    }
}
}
```

This is my first attempt to implement DI using  ninject.

I am not sure how to resolve the error "The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context". I went through this question [Compilation Error with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082008/compilation-error-with-ninject) but still not sure how to solve this. How can this be resolved. It will be great if I can get the code sample so that I can understand much better

**Edit :**

```
namespace DependencyInjection
{
class Program  
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        var samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>(); -----> Exception Line
        samurai.Attack("Hello");
   }       
}

class Samurai
{
    readonly IWeapon _weapon;
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        _weapon = weapon;
    }
    public void Attack(string target)
    {
        _weapon.Hit(target);
    }
}

interface IWeapon
{
    void Hit(string target);
}

class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sword - ", target);
    }
}

class Arrow : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrow - ", target);
    }
}
}
```

The above code results in "MethodAccessException was unhandled" on line var samurai = kernel.Get(); I search Google but was not able to find any concrete solution

**Exception**

```
System.MethodAccessException was unhandled
  Message="DependencyInjection.Sword..ctor()"
  Source="Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly"
  StackTrace:
       at DynamicInjector84db385a6cfb4301b146100b5027c44a(Object[] )
       at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
       at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
       at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__4(IContext context)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)
       at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)
       at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Create>b__0(ITarget target)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
       at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
       at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__4(IContext context)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__aa`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters)
       at DependencyInjection.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Sandboxes\C_Sharp\DependencyInjection\DependencyInjection\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: You can fix this by [using Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) :)

Comment: @bentayloruk: Do you really think Ninject is broken like that??

Comment: @mauricio-scheffer No.  I have never used Ninject.  I had hoped the smile would indicate the presence of a joke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because `Bind` is normally a method on the kernel, so you should do this outside the module. Also you should create your bindings before resolving Samurai, so swap the last two lines around:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    kernel.Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();
    var samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
```

}

The reason why `Bind` sometimes works without kernel is because you probably saw tutorials doing that inside a module. `NinjectModule` has a protected `Bind` method that performs the same function:

```
public class NinjaModule : NinjectModule {
    public void Load() {
       Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf()
       Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    }
}
```

Either method is appropriate, when your bindings get a bit complex, it's advisable to put them into modules.

**EDIT** Make sure all of your classes and interfaces are public, otherwise Ninject can't execute them. When accessibility modifier is not specified, it defaults to `internal`. This explains `MethodAccessException`.

Comment: @Igor Zevaka Thanks! But after modifying the code, it results in MethodAccessException. I've updated my question can you pl check?

Comment: Updated answer, you need to bind Samurai as well as all of it's dependencies in order to get this example to work.

Comment: Can you post the full exception text and stacktrace?

Comment: Make all you classes and interfaces `public`.

Answer (score 1):

```
kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
```

or do the binding in a class that inherits from `NinjectModule`.

Comment: +1 for extend NinjectModule. Just why didn't he call it `Ninjector` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The Bind() method is define on [IBindingRoot](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingRoot.cs). Both [StandardKernel](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/StandardKernel.cs) and [NinjectModule](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Modules/NinjectModule.cs) derives from [BindingRoot](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Syntax/BindingRoot.cs) which implements IBindingRoot.

You can bind your services on the kernel

```
public static void Main()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    // Optional, Ninject will try to resolve any non-registered concrete type.
    kernel.Bind<Samuari>().ToSelf();

    var samurai = kernel.Get<Samuari>();
}
```

or by using a Ninject module

```
public class WeaponModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        // Optional, Ninject will try to resolve any non-registered concrete type.
        Bind<Samuari>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

and then load the module

```
public static void Main()
{
    var module = new WeaponModule();
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(module);
    var weapon = kernel.Get<IWeapon>();
}
```